# Remove all files from within documentDirectory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I am making an audio app, and the user can download files locally stored to the `documentDirectory` using `FileManager`.

Next, I'd like to allow the user to delete all files using a button. In the documentation, there is a [method to remove items](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem).

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func deleteDirectoryButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this won't build with an error `Ambiguous reference to member 'removeItem(atPath:)'`.

Is there a better approach to access the `documentDirectory` and remove all files from the directory in one swoop?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all the error occurs because the signature of the API is wrong. It's just `removeItem(at:)` without the other parameters.

A second issue is that you are going to delete the `Documents` directory itself rather than the files **in** the directory which you are discouraged from doing that.

You have to get the *contents* of the directory and add a check for example to delete only MP3 files. A better solution would be to use a subfolder.

```
let documentsUrl = URL.documentsDirectory

do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl,
                                                               includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                               options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    for fileURL in fileURLs where fileURL.pathExtension == "mp3" {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)   
    }
} catch  { print(error) }
```

Side note: It is highly recommended to use always the URL related API of `FileManager`.

Comment: While both of the upvoted answers were solutions, I chose this one because it allowed me to achieve the desired result without creating a temp directory (and therefore not requiring a change to the methods for my file storage already in the codebase).

Comment: This is perfect solution to delete files including folders as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
func clearAllFiles() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
        
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        
    print("Directory: \(paths)")
        
    do {
        let fileName = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: paths)
            
        for file in fileName {
            // For each file in the directory, create full path and delete the file
            let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent(file).absoluteURL
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use code as Follow

to save AudioFile in Document Directory as

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL
    {
        //Get Basic URL
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        /// Enter a Directory Name in which files will be saved
        let dataPath1 = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("folder_name_enter")
        let dataPath = dataPath1.appendingPathComponent("folder inside directory if required (name)")
        //Handler
        do
        {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return dataPath
    }
```

**Delete**

```
func clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory()
    {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let tempDirPath = dirPath.appending("/folder_name/\(inside_directoryName)")

        do {
            let folderPath = tempDirPath
            let paths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: tempDirPath)
            for path in paths
            {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: "\(folderPath)/\(path)")
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

**Saving Method**

```
getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(audioName).wav")
```

**Deletion Method**

```
/// Just call
clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

This my extension for remove all files and caches from directory.

```
// MARK: - FileManager extensions

extension FileManager {
    
    /// Remove all files and caches from directory.
    public static func removeAllFilesDirectory() {
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let mainPaths = [
            FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)[0],
            FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)[0]
        ]
        mainPaths.forEach { mainPath in
            do {
                let content = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: mainPath)
                content.forEach { file in
                    do {
                        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: URL(fileURLWithPath: mainPath).appendingPathComponent(file).path)
                    } catch {
                        // Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                // Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 5

##### Delete the whole folder:

> If you'd like to delete a whole folder you can simply do this:

```swift
func deleteFolder(_ folderName: String, completion: () -> Void) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let directory = fileManager.cachesDirectory().appendingPathComponent(folderName)
    _ = try? fileManager.removeItem(at: directory)
    completion()
}
```

##### Delete certain files based on their name:

> This will loop through all the files and remove all that contain the

```swift
func removeFiles(containing: String, completion: () -> Void) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let directory = fileManager.cachesDirectory()
    
    if let fileNames = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directory.path) {
        for file in fileNames {
            if file.contains(containing) {
                let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: directory.path).appendingPathComponent(file).absoluteURL
                _ = try? fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath)
            }
        }
    }
    completion()
}
```

Comment: Your code has an error with swift5: FileManager does not have cachesDirectory!